# Bluetooth server incoming buffer handling

Tags: java, string, sockets, bluetooth, buffer

I have the following Bluetooth Server class that extends a `Thread` to listen for incoming stream:

```
class SeverThread extends Thread{
    bytes[] inBuffer = new bytes[1024];
    int bytes; 
    while(true){ 
        try{
            bytes = inputStream.read(inBuffer);
        }catch(IOException e){
                    // handle exception 
        }
        System.out.println(new String(inBuffer));
    }
}
```

**The problem with this implementation:**

When client first sends `"Sanjeev"` , output is `"Sanjeev"`. Cool. After that, the client sends `smk`, the output now is `smkjeev`. Note that first 3 letters - `san` - have become `smk`. Now when the client sends `hell`, the output is `helleev`. If the client again sends `"Sanjeev"` then output is `"Sanjeev"` , because length of received string is same as the used space inside the buffer.

This is the expected behavior based on above code. But it's an unintended bug. I want the outputs to be `Sanjeev` , `smk` and `hello` respectively. The problem is apparent. The same buffer in memory is being used to take all the incoming words.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Possible approaches:

1. Clear or refresh the buffer for every loop inside `while(true)`. I don't know how to do this.
2. Move the declaration of `inBuffer` *inside* the `while` loop. But this will continuously allocate memory, a big wastage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
bytes = inputStream.read(inBuffer);
inBuffer[bytes] = '\0';
```